# How can I reference the same class multiple times within another class?

Tags: ruby, mongodb, mongoid

How can I reference the same class twice (or multiple times) within another class with Mongoid?

```
class User
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :email

  references_many :messages, :stored_as => :array #all messages where the user acts as a sender
  references_many :messages, :stored_as => :array #all messages where the user acts as a receiver
end

class Message
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :Text

  references_one :user #this should be the sender
  references_one :user #this should be the receiver
end
```

Answer (score 0):

references_many :sent_messages, :stored_as => :array, :class_name => 'Message'

and

references_one :sender, :class_name => 'User'

Comment: and don't forget to do :inverse_of

Comment: This solution is in the current (2012) MongoID-Version not working anymore